# Refreshing QTableView after loading new data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I'm trying to update a table/table model after loading a new csv so it shows the new values. Would updating the widget also some how manage this? I've cut down the code quite a bit below. You can use any 2 column csv:

0, 0, 
 0, 0, 
 0, 0,

```
import pandas as pd

from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


def read_data(fname):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=',', usecols=(0, 1), header=None)
    df = df.dropna(how='any')
    df = df[pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='coerce').notnull()]
    data_arr = df.to_numpy(dtype='float64')

    return data_arr


class CustomTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.load_data(data)

    def load_data(self, data):
        self.input_x = data[:, 0]
        self.input_y = data[:, 1]
        self.column_count = 2
        self.row_count = len(self.input_x)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.row_count

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.column_count

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return ("x", "y")[section]
        else:
            return "{}".format(section)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        column = index.column()
        row = index.row()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column == 0:
                return str(self.input_x[row])
            elif column == 1:
                return str(self.input_y[row])
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white)
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return QtCore.Qt.AlignRight

        return None


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        try:
            self.data
        except AttributeError:
            self.open_csv()

        self.model = CustomTableModel(self.data)
        self.table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table_view.setModel(self.model)

        resize = QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents
        self.horizontal_header = self.table_view.horizontalHeader()
        self.vertical_header = self.table_view.verticalHeader()
        self.horizontal_header.setSectionResizeMode(resize)
        self.vertical_header.setSectionResizeMode(resize)
        self.horizontal_header.setStretchLastSection(False)

        # Creating layout
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.file_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('CSV Import', self)
        self.file_button.clicked.connect(self.open_csv)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.table_view)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.file_button)

        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def open_csv(self):
        filename, *_ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, self.tr('Open CSV'),
                                                             self.tr("~/Desktop/"), self.tr('Files (*.csv)'))
        self.data = read_data(filename)
        return None


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Linear Plotter')
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.menu = self.menuBar()
        self.file_menu = self.menu.addMenu('File')

        exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Exit', self)
        exit_action.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.Quit)
        exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file_menu.addAction(exit_action)

        self.status = self.statusBar()
        self.status.showMessage('Data loaded and plotted')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = Widget()
    window = MainWindow(widget)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Not sure if QWidget.update() would work? I could not get it working.

Comment: What do you mean by update()? I can't see it in the code

Comment: Sorry:   qwidget.update()

Comment: After `self.data = read_data(filename)` you will then need to update the models associated with the table (lines 7-9 of Widget.__init__), and then call update on self.table_view (if that is even needed at that point)

Comment: Calling `update` is not related to the contents of the model (the view updates itself whenever the contents change, assuming the model is correctly implemented), also it would be useless, since you should update the *viewport* of the view instead (`self.table_view.viewport().update()`). Can't you just create a new model and set it again using `setModel()` as you did in in the `__init__`?

Comment: Pretty simple thanks! Had to make a new method and set the button to that.

Answer (score 0):

once the model has been assigned to the QTableView via `.setModel` then the view is informed that the model has changed via the model signal `.layoutChanged`

so try `self.model.layoutChanged.emit()`